# 2013 iMac won't boot up

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup

Not really good with all this, and would appreciate any help.

I am using an old iMac (I think mid 2013) with the internal 1TB HDD that I think I had upgraded to Catalina.

I have been having boot issues, initially with the boot stalling with the progress bar at 99% -- stalled for hours or all day.  Today, after going into recovery mode, I am getting the flashing folder with the `?` on boot up.

In Disk Utility, I can see the Disk "1 TB APPLE HDD ST100LMO24" and but underneath that is an unmounted partition called "disk0s2".

I can run disk utility to repair the disk, and this indicates the partition map is OK.  But I can't repair the unmounted partition.

If I go to Startup Disk option in Recovery, there is no startup disk identified.

I've tried to boot up holding down the option key, but this only takes me direct to internet recovery option, again without identifying a start up disk.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add to your question from recovery mode terminal (top menu/utilities /terminal) the result of command : `diskutil list internal `?

Comment: Although diagnosing this without access to the device is hard this sounds to me like a hardware failure of the drive. Is there anything on the drive that you need or is losing all the data for you no problem? If the first, then stop doing anything with it and look at bringing your Mac to a professional data recovery service.

Comment: Hi Jean, if I am doing that correctly, it returns "Could not find disk: internal"

Comment: If it is a hardware failure, I am wondering if I could get a few more years out of this device booting from an external SSD?  There is data including a music library on the HDD that I dont want to loose, although I think I have a time machine back up from a year or so ago.

Comment: Most likely the drive is corrupt, failing, or has another EOL (end of life) problem. Get an external disk, preferably an SSD, do a fresh install of MacOS on that disk. When done installing, boot from the external SSD. IF your internal hard drive was not using APFS, you can use Diskwarrior to rebuild the directory of the internal drive and there is a good chance you can boot from the internal drive once more to backup your data.